# What is this distribution formulated with w, m and sum sign?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, machine-learning, bayesian

I have a binary classification problem, part of which is defined as follows :

p(x|y=1) $\sim w (m_1 , \sum_1$)

and

p(x|y=0) $\sim w (m_0 , \sum_0$)

Where $\sum_1$ is a covariance matrix :

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \sigma^2 & 0\\
        0 & \sigma^2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

So what is this distribution?

Note : I am supposed to find a generative model for classification.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Well, to begin with, this is NOT a covariance matrix.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Changed the order of rows :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the lecture notes , it turns out this is a normal distribution around mean $m_1$ and variance $\sigma$. The different notation is because the means are vectors instead of scalars. The dimension of m is equal to the dimension of the covariance matrix.

Comment: Good that you've found your answer. Please also mark the question as answered! It is quite helpful for other users :)

Comment: @hejseb I forgot after waiting for days, thanks for the reminder :)